# OneDrive Windows 10 - how to force sync

Tags: sync, office365, onedrive

So, this is the case:

1. go to `https://mycompany-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myuser/_layouts/...`
2. Click `Sync`
3. Next, next, .. `Open my onedrive folder`
4. Copy files to `local folder`
5. Waiting to OneDrive to Upload files...
6. Send link to boss
7. Got complaint: "where is my files?"
8. Look at the OneDrive "log", saw "Uploaded"
9. Look at the web "nothing here"
10. Look around and around, `Ctrl F5`, Quit Onedrive then open it again, nothing work.

Can't figure out what happened, just have to say sorry to boss, unlink account, then sync again (thanks God I have backup)

So, is there any way for us to `onedrive push origin master --force`?

Comment: You should ask your IT folks about this.

Comment: You can troubleshoot the issue according to [Fix OneDrive sync problems](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/onedrive%C2%A0sync-error-0b10108f-8459-4a7a-b912-28f8adec5a81). You can use the OneDrive sync troubleshooting virtual agent to have a try. If the issue could be reproduced, you can try to reset OneDrive.

Comment: @sjngm when speaking of business environments there are two prevailing factors: first, the business may have set policies controlling these things, and second, the business is responsible for making certain their systems work and business staff going to 3rd party sources to solve problems is not at all a good thing. It is not in any way the only answer, but questions that are about business IT and that are asked by end users are definitely and correctly answered that way. Many IT staff ask their questions here and get answers, and many of us volunteers are also professional IT staff